# Copy matches of recursive search to a new location

Tags: linux, find, cp

I want to search a directory recursively and copy all XML files to a new location.  I can identify the files with:

```
ls -R | grep .xml$
```

or with full paths with:

```
find . -name \*.xml
```

Results of normal `ls` calls can be passed to `cp` like so:

```
cp `ls` ./newdir
```

But I can't seem to get this approach working with recursive searches – `cp` misreads the resulting grep string and creates lots of empty files.  The closest looking [SU question](https://superuser.com/a/385676/210314) – using `locate` – fails to move any files.

---

**Edit:**

Alternative method:

```
find . -name \*.xml > xml_list.txt
while read p; do   cp $p ./newdir; done <xml_list.txt
```

.. results in a list of errors (longer than number of lines) in format:

```
cp: pathfilenamesegment: No such file or directory
```

.. where `pathfilenamesegment` are segments of file/path strings that happen to be separated by spaces.  Bash is apparently not applying the strings as wholes but in segments.  The iterator is however working properly as substituting `echo 1` prints the same number of times as rows in `xml_list.txt`.

Any way to force bash to recognise lines as whole strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec cp -vt /newdir {} +
```

This searches for all files ending with `.xml`. Then `find` executes `cp -vt /newdir` on them. With the `+` character `find` runs the `cp` command as few invocations as possible, stringing together as many arguments as the shell allows.

**Edit**: if your `cp` hasn't the `-t` option, use this:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec cp -v {} /newdir/ \;
```

Comment: Error: `cp: illegal option -- t`

Comment: Your cp hasn't  the `-t` option, use: `find . -name "*.xml" -exec cp -v {} /newdir/ \;` instead.